# TBB + FoxyProxy = Safe?

Tags: tor-browser-bundle, anonymity, security, firefox, plugin

Can I safely use FoxyProxy together with the Tor Browser Bundle?

I like to have an additional hop after the Tor exit node.
Therefore I am considering the use of the FoxyProxy plugin to
the Tor Browser Bundle. (Yes, I know I actually should not use
browser add-ons.)

Yet, I am highly suspicious that FoxyProxy will screw up my anonymity.

**I am afraid that it will route all traffic directly through the proxy,
bypassing the Tor network altogether.**
(Changing the default 127.0.0.1 to X.X.X.X | FoxyProxy not being able to chain proxies.)

Are my fears justified or can I safely use FoxyProxy?

Comment: As far as I know your answer is yes. You are safe with Foxyproxy as far as I know.

Answer (score 1):

No, I would not do this.  You see, this is how tor works:

Browser ==>  Locally hosted socks5 proxy ==> Internal functions ==> tor network.

Unless your proxy acted as a bridge to the tor network, this would not work.

Answer (score 0):

Even if you're behind a router, that will silently route all the traffic via Tor - take a look at this https://github.com/samyk/evercookie ...